# Best way to compare two database tables of differing types and compare their data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, drupal-6

I have two database tables, one in MYSQL and one in MSSQL. Both have similar data, and one is based on data from another. They're in two different databases because one is a remote system that is administered and the local system is a Drupal installation which I'm using to show the data in a more friendly manner through a custom module.

For example, I have a table of this sort of structure in MSSQL:

```
ID | Title | Description | Other fields I don't care about
```

And based on pulling data from this table I generate a table in MYSQL:

```
local_id | remote_id | title | description
```

When the module is initialized, it goes out and does a select from the MSSQL table and generates records and populates the local database. Remote_id is the ID field in the MSSQL database so we can reference the two records together.

I need to sync up this data, deleting records locally which no longer exist on the remote table and creating new records which do not exist locally, and also update all rows information.

Problem is, that sort of requires at least 2 different transactions with possible by-row transactions as well. Example:

**To sync local to Remote and remove non-existent remote records:**

```
Select remote_id from local_table;
  For Each remote_id ( select ID, title, description FROM remote_table where ID = remote_id )
    If record exists
      UPDATE local_table WHERE remote_id = row_id
    Else
      DELETE FROM local_table where remote_id = row_id
```

**Then we need at least one other transaction to get new records (I could update here too if I didn't do it in the previous loop):**

```
Select ID, title, description from remote_table;
  For each ID ( Select remote_id from local_table )
    If does not exist
      INSERT INTO local_table (VALUES)
```

So that's a lot of db activity. It would be easier if the tables were of the same type but as it is that's the only way I know how to do it. Is there a better way? Could I just pull both result sets into an associative array and compare that way and only do the transactions necessary to remove and create? I'm unsure.

Comment: Why don't you just query the remote database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Narf. I'll need to query both the remote and local databases to compare the two. I'm seeking the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: I mean why are you trying to get a local copy of the table? It's obvious that you have direct remote access to it ...

Comment: @Narf - I'm trying to bring remote data into a drupal installation. In order for it to create nodes it has to bring the remote data into the local database and save them as nodes. I need to compare the remote rows with the nodes that I have currently created on the site and edit or remove them accordingly. I could directly access the database (and I am doing so now) but it limits the ability to do things in the drupal system unless you bring the data in as a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of ways to do this based on the system you house. 
The first assumption i am making is that you have 2 databases and you want to sync data between these 2 
that is MSSQL db must pull data from MySQL and vice versa

Your approach of using associative arrays is good but what if there are 100 columns in the table? ( in your case it is not but the approach is not future proof) 
So to update 1 row you need to make "n" column comparisons if there are 100 rows, then there will be 100*n comparisons

Have a look at MySQL REPLACE, INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY clauses that might help you - i dont know if there are such clauses in MSSQL

You can do other things like - have a "last_updated" column in each database table - whenever a column in the table gets updated, this time-stamp field must be updated

This way you can tell if a row in either database table was updated ( by comparing it to your old timestamp value) and only update those rows

logic would be in these lines

```
to sync local to remote 
foreach localrow 
  get the common_id of the row 
  get the timestamp of the row 
  check if a row with this common_id exists in the remote table 
  if no then insert 
  if yes then 
    compare timestamps between local and remote row 
    if local row timestamp > remote row timestamp then update remote row
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do a row by row operations you could do set based operations. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO local_table (vales)
SELECT .. FROM  remote_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select ... FROM local_table WHERE remote_table.field = local_table.field and ...)
```

In order to do that you'll need to add a linked server See [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). You can create a link from SQL Server to any server listed on the page. This includes any Database that has an ODBC driver which MySQL does.

I am not aware if MySQL is capable of doing the reverse.

Comment: I don't believe that will work because there's no way to integrate the remote_table data because it requires a seperate DB call since one is in SQL server and the other is in MySQL. You can't do both in a mysql_query statement.. could you?

Comment: @Oranges13. I've updated my answer. Hopefully I've made the Linked Server bit clearer which allows you to connect across databases

Comment: I still don't think this is possible in the context of a drupal installation. I don't believe I could feed something like this into drupal's db abstraction functions and have it work successfully. And I cannot modify the databases in any form so I don't believe this will work.

Comment: Once you set up the linked server it would be like calling a stored proc or accessing objects on SQL Server. Drupal should be able to  handle that.